# Play remote video with Basic authentication in html using video tag

Tags: html, asp.net, video, iframe

I am building a website using asp.net. The website is hosted by IIS server. I can access the website using the link : https://ipaddress.
The website is supposed to access the videos from the videos folder which is present in the same location. I have enables the Basic Authentication for the Videos folder I use the following codes to play the video from the folder:

```
     <video   controls controlsList="nodownload"  id="Set1" runat="server">

      <source src="http://username:password@ipaddress/Videos/Course1/Universe.mp4"/>

       </video>
```

But it still asks for username and password. However if I use same link to play video with iframe tag, it works. Since iframe tags not working in IE, that is why I cannot use that. 
I also tried to bind C# codes to programmatically let the user log in :

```
          <video   controls controlsList="nodownload"  id="Set1" 
          runat="server">
     <%var client = new System.Net.WebClient {Credentials = new 
       System.Net.NetworkCredential("us", "password")};
      var response =

 client.DownloadString("link"); 
    %>
        <source src="link"/>

     </video>
```

But it also did not work. I have spent about half of my day on doing research but nothing worked so far.
Please give me suggestions.

Comment: "if I use same link to play video with tag, it works" -- can you attach the code that works? It's unclear what "play video with tag" is.

Comment: BTW, iframe is well supported since IE6+

Comment: I mean if I use same codes but replace video tag with iframe then it plays video without asking for username and password but it does not work in IE